# JSR 303 - How to get validator instance programmatically by annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I could not find a way to apply a constraint conditionally, so I would like to make a validator that applies other annotations conditionally. I would like to be able to do:

```java
@IfNotNull(validateWith = Email.class)
```

Then in my validator class, get the annotation classes from `validateWith`, get their validator instances, and validate via those if this value is not null. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to lookup a `Validator` instance by annotation.

Is there a way to do that or apply a constraint conditionally?

I am using Hibernate as the validation provider.